Do any philosophers hold that a person needs to think thoroughly about their drives?
During my life I've met a lot of people, and I've realized that a lot of them don't seem to grasp completely what makes them happy. I've met some that hate immigration but arent able to express why they feel that way, some that will consume tons of a certain type of media without feeling an ounce of emotion, and others that will talk constantly how having more money would be what would make them finally happy, without having any exact idea of what they would do with that money.
It seems incredible to me, because most of these problems can easily be solved by having some personal hours of introspection about what makes one happy, what motivates them, and what they should strive for, but so much people seem to live their daily lives just following routines, hoping that something changes in their life or waiting for the day their current routine ends (graduation, retirement, ...). Does the average person self-examine? Does the average person think about their drives and motivations?
Do any philosophers hold that the a person need think thoroughly about their drives?

Have you used your understanding of your own drives to already do what makes you really happy, so now you are really happy? Or are you just now planning to do that, while still at the moment living more or less like everybody else who you believe does not understand their drives?

I came to the conclusion a long time ago that to be happy I just need a good group of friends and free time to be able to hang out with them, so I started meeting more new people and being more open. I can say that I'm pretty happy and working towards a happier future. The people I mentioned seemed to never have actually had this realisation, and so they live without this objective to try and improve their happiness.

Know thyself is the beginning and end of philosophy. But why? Three significant teachers from the western and indian systems  are combined in  this answer towards this.

This is a consequence of know thyself maxim, fairly common in ethics since Socrates, see SEP, Obligations to Oneself. Kant writes, for example, "This command is know (scrutinize, fathom) yourself... That is, know your heart – whether it is good or evil, whether the source of your actions is pure or impure, and what can be imputed to you as belonging originally to the substance of a human being..."

Some philosophers, such as Friedrich Nietzsche and Sigmund Freud, argue that individuals should deeply reflect on their drives. This self-awareness can help one understand underlying motivations and achieve greater personal autonomy. Nietzsche, in particular, emphasized that unexamined drives can control behavior without conscious understanding, potentially leading to unfulfilled lives. Exploring one’s drives is crucial to personal growth and living authentically.

I would describe what you are talking about as the direction of wisdom, as cultivating wisdom. Which was really the core topic for Ancient Greeks, but is I think oddly neglected in modern discourse.
Reconciling or integrating who we are in different contexts, in different moods, our long and short term needs, etc, I call finding the integrated centre of our concerns, which requires an active practice to keep aware of, that we can relate to Socrates favourite Delphic Maxim: 'Know thyself'. And by knowing it we can act from that integrated self, rather than say our impulsive or angry self, that's only present temporarily.
A powerful strength of acting with this self-knowledge, is in becoming better at solving apparent dilemmas. Another strength is resisting rhetoric, like the anti-immigrant strategy politicians use that's made really clear by the Southern Strategy in the US. See fuller discussion and background in this answer: Wisdom and John Vervaeke's awakening from the meaning crises?
Happiness is a big topic in philosophy. Aristotle had this term 'eudaimonia' which is often translated as happiness, and he saw every living thing as striving towards their own version of it. Aristotle spent a substantial amount of his time in exile studying botany, and drew on the analogy of seeds fulfilling their potential to describe eudaimonia, so another translation of the word is 'human flourishing'. The literal translation is 'good spiritedness', but Ancient Greeks would have been most familiar with the specific spirits called daimons as the hearth-spirit, said to be kept happy by never letting the hearth go out, so we might also describe the term as 'keeping a well-kindled spirit'. Socrates described having a personal daimon that would forbid him from things but not tell him what to do, and it's pretty clear he meant what we would call conscience, and that by living in alignment with it we can live without regrets from acting in an unintegrated way, even if we are made to drink hemlock for it.
The danger of casual talk about happiness is that most often it is the flag we plant on the hill we want to climb, and think if we just get there we will be happy, so we think we know what our happiness is. But we forget, or avoid thinking about, all the times getting what we thought we wanted did not in fact make us happy. If we don't come to know ourselves, all our striving risks being in vain. Don't belittle or dismiss people who haven't done that, it takes wisdom, and that is difficult to get. Just try to know yourself, practice your own wisdom, and that will be the best way to point others there.
Taking immigration as paradigmatic. Jonathan Haidt & co's Moral Foundations theory can help us understand the appeal. Some articles that introduce the ideas are The moral matrix that influences the way people vote and Why working-class people vote conservative. Their research points ti the idea that when we feel under threat, like near a border-conflict, or there's a pandemic, we have a mode we are more likely to go towards: in-group preference and more hostility yo strangers, less tolerance of differences, more concern about hygeine cleanliness and appearance. We can understand how there are biological roots to that. We can also understand how rightwing media constantly invoke threat and crisis, towards 'activating' this mode. Trying to approach someone with hostility to immigrants, who considers them dangerous and dirty say, doesn't work well to change minds. There's a good article from Psychology Today, How to ChangeSomeone's Mind, According to Neuroscience, and the TLDR is first establish your shared values, show that you have them, and that you have faith that they are fundamentally a good person trying to do the right thing, and try to show them you are too, eg that you are open-minded. Then you can get in to issues and cases, with that as background context. The dialogues of Socrates are very good as models for doing this, with lots of open questions and developing the discussion using the other person's responses. I recently pointed out how 16% of all Nobel Prizes were given to people born outside the USA who became citizens there, and that the H1B academic route to citizenship has been critical to the US economy - that's a way to start someone thinking differently. UK from Windrush to Brexit, Japan's very serious demographic and economic problems (they have the lowest immigration of any large developed economy), and the fall-out from wars Western countries started or made worse, are some other issues to bring up.
Just be curious, keep asking people why they think what they think. That, is philosophy..!

I think we all have our own experiences in life and these experiences influence our perspectives about everything, all that has happened in your life has led up to you asking this question.
Now let me say if the idea of "happiness" is so interesting then you should focus on your own and not worry about what it means to other people, no matter what you believe in we only have one shot on this beautiful planet, it's best if we make the most of it. You may never understand why they do certain things but that's because you will never have their exact experiences. Happiness is subjective and it means something different to everyone you ask. It's okay if you don't understand them, maybe a couple more hours of introspection could help you realize this.
As long as you are happy then you shouldn't spend time trying to make others' happiness mean something to you. In optimistic nihilism, we gain happiness from meaning and purpose in life. A lot of us try to find happiness in external factors that are, for the most part, out of our control.
We let material possessions and our relationships with others dictate our emotions. We have a choice to make in troubling situations, we can feel sad, angry, or act stubbornly or we can change our perception and take back control of ourselves. Base your happiness off everyday things, express gratitude in all you do, and base your success on the amount of effort you put in and not the judgment of others. Happiness is a short-lived emotion from things going well, but joy and contentment contribute to the long-lasting peace within oneself, one must strive to know the dichotomy of control. Only then can you have joy. Nothing is missing but you, here in the present moment, live thankfully and create your meaning.

Good 1st answer! I've added some paragraph breaks for readability. Please modify as you prefer

@Rushi No Need! Thanks for the help.
